# I want to show an image with static sizes, independent of monitor resolutions

Tags: html, css, image, size

As monitor resolutions are changed, images are shown in different size even their sizes are coded in metric values(cm, mm...), on monitors.

Is there any method to fix the monitored size of images in an exact values?

Comment: Hmm always 150px or always 25vw? ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you but still, they are different in "real size". I want to make the displayed size same, like 100mm width on any monitors.

Answer (score 0):

For the images you can do that in CSS :
You need to use relative lengths to resolve you problem :

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

**CSS**

```
.image {
width:...%;
height:...%;
}
```

**XHTML**

```
<img src="image/image_name.jpg" class="image" alt="image_alt" />
```

Comment: I mean "the real displayed size" : if I code it in 100px, its length is about 23.6mm on my ultra wide monitor, but 28mm on other regular monitor. I want to make them equal. Thanks. :)

Comment: So use Relative Lengths https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp ex: %, vh ....